# Бессуффиксный способ что это значит

Tags: словообразование

Пожалуйста, поясните, что такое бессуффиксный способ образования?

Answer (score 3):

Подписать - подпись, синий - синь. **Как образуются слова: без помощи словообразовательных элементов или с помощью нулевого суффикса?**

"Бессуффиксный спо́соб словообразова́ния — способ образования слов, при котором суффикс и окончание производящего слова отбрасываются: резать — резь.

Бессуффиксным способом могут образовываться только имена существительные. 
Данный способ используется при образовании имен существительных как от глаголов (нагревать — нагрев), так и от имен прилагательных (глубокий — глубь).

Некоторые исследователи считают этот способ **разновидностью суффиксального способа словообразования — нулевой суффиксацией — и выделяют в словах такого типа нулевой суффикс".**

Всё-таки **нулевая суффиксация** - более логичное и более содержательное название, чем бессуффиксный способ, при этом речь идет **об одном и том же способе** образования слов.

Answer (score 1):

Пример бессуфиксного способа словообразования: *поискать => поиск*. Суффикса нет.

P.S. Пример из ЕГЭ, в котором моя дочка ошиблась. Она решила, что *поиск* – от *иск*, приставочным способом. ((

Comment: А может быть, здесь приставочно-суффиксальный способ: искать - поиск? Приставка ПО, нулевой суффикс. Для такого образования семантика более подходящая. Из словаря: поиск - это попытка найти, а искать - стараться найти, обнаружить, поискать - некоторое время искать.

Comment: В словаре М.Т. Баранова написано, что слово поиск образовано от поискать при помощи усечения.

Comment: Но в слове "поиск" приставка ПО не имеет значение "искать некоторое время", как в глаголе "поискать". А поход, повар как образуются? Они вроде бы должны иметь одну схему образования.